Issues rendering a cube in Direct3D11
I started studying DirectX recently and I'm developing an "game engine". For now I just want to draw a cube, but for some reason that I don't know why, it doesn't draw it at all. It's probably some stupid error but I don't know much about DirectX so I don't really know what is the problem :,)
Any ideas?
Main.cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")             
#pragma comment( lib, "dxgi.lib")        
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d11sdklayers.h>
#include <directxmath.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <dxgi.h>
#include "Variables.h"

bool InitializeDirect3dApp(HINSTANCE hInstance);
void CleanUp();
bool InitScene();
void UpdateScene();
void DrawScene();

bool InitializeDirect3dApp(HINSTANCE hInstance);

const int Width = 1920;
const int Height = 1080;

bool InitializeWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    int ShowWnd,
    int width, int height,
    bool windowed);

int messageloop();

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd,
    UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
    if (!InitializeWindow(hInstance, nShowCmd, Width, Height, true))
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"An error has ocurred during window initialization!",
            L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    if (!InitializeDirect3dApp(hInstance)) {
        MessageBox(0, L"An error has occurred during Direct3D initialization!", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    InitializeDirect3dApp(hInstance);
    messageloop();
    CleanUp();

    return 0;
}

bool InitializeWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    int ShowWnd,
    int width, int height,
    bool windowed)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);    //Size of our windows class
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;    //class styles
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;    //Default windows procedure function
    wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;    //Extra bytes after our wc structure
    wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;    //Extra bytes after our windows instance
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;    //Instance to current application
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);    //Title bar Icon
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);    //Default mouse Icon
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2);    //Window bg color
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;    //Name of the menu attached to our window
    wc.lpszClassName = WndClassName;    //Name of our windows class
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO); //Icon in your taskbar

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"An error has ocurred during class registration!",
            L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        WndClassName,
        windowName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        width,
        height,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hwnd)
    {

        MessageBox(NULL, L"An error has ocurred during window creation!",
            L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, ShowWnd);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    return true;
}

//Initializes D3D11
bool InitializeDirect3dApp(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    DXGI_MODE_DESC bufferDesc;

    ZeroMemory(&bufferDesc, sizeof(DXGI_MODE_DESC));

    bufferDesc.Width = Width;
    bufferDesc.Height = Height;
    bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    bufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    bufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    bufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc = {};

    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 3;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = Width;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = Height;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

    hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &SwapChain, &d3d11Device, NULL, &d3d11DevCon);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"An error has ocurred during D3D11 Device Creation!",
            TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ID3D11Texture2D* BackBuffer;
    hr = SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&BackBuffer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"An error has ocurred during getting buffer!",
            TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hr = d3d11Device->CreateRenderTargetView(BackBuffer, nullptr, &renderTargetView);
    BackBuffer->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"An error has ocurred during creatting render target!",
            TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc;

    depthStencilDesc.Width = Width;
    depthStencilDesc.Height = Height;
    depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    depthStencilDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthStencilDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    d3d11Device->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, NULL, &depthStencilBuffer);
    d3d11Device->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencilBuffer, NULL, &depthStencilView);

    d3d11DevCon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTargetView, depthStencilView);

    return true;
}

void CleanUp()
{
    SwapChain->Release();
    d3d11Device->Release();
    d3d11DevCon->Release();
    renderTargetView->Release();
    squareVertBuffer->Release();
    squareIndexBuffer->Release();
    VS->Release();
    PS->Release();
    VS_Buffer->Release();
    PS_Buffer->Release();
    vertLayout->Release();
    depthStencilView->Release();
    depthStencilBuffer->Release();
    cbPerObjectBuffer->Release();
    WireFrame->Release();
}

bool InitScene()
{
    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"VertexShader.hlsl", nullptr, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, "vs_main", "vs_5_0",
        flags, 0, &vs_blob_ptr, &error_blob);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        if (error_blob) {
            OutputDebugStringA((char*)error_blob->GetBufferPointer());
            error_blob->Release();
        }
        if (vs_blob_ptr) { vs_blob_ptr->Release(); }
    }

    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"VertexShader.hlsl", nullptr, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, "ps_main", "ps_5_0",
        flags, 0, &ps_blob_ptr, &error_blob);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        if (error_blob) {
            OutputDebugStringA((char*)error_blob->GetBufferPointer());
            error_blob->Release();
        }
        if (ps_blob_ptr) { ps_blob_ptr->Release(); }
    }

    hr = d3d11Device->CreateVertexShader(
        vs_blob_ptr->GetBufferPointer(),
        vs_blob_ptr->GetBufferSize(),
        NULL,
        &VS);

    hr = d3d11Device->CreatePixelShader(
        ps_blob_ptr->GetBufferPointer(),
        ps_blob_ptr->GetBufferSize(),
        NULL,
        &PS);

    d3d11DevCon->VSSetShader(VS, NULL, 0);
    d3d11DevCon->PSSetShader(PS, NULL, 0);

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC indexBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&indexBufferDesc, sizeof(indexBufferDesc));

    indexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    indexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * 12 * 3;
    indexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    indexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    indexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;

    iinitData.pSysMem = indices;
    d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&indexBufferDesc, &iinitData, &squareIndexBuffer);
    d3d11DevCon->IASetIndexBuffer(squareIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc));
    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 8;
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferData, sizeof(vertexBufferData));
    vertexBufferData.pSysMem = v;
    hr = d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexBufferData, &squareVertBuffer);
    d3d11DevCon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &squareVertBuffer, &vertex_stride, &vertex_offset);

    hr = d3d11Device->CreateInputLayout(inputElementDesc, numElements, vs_blob_ptr->GetBufferPointer(),
        vs_blob_ptr->GetBufferSize(), &input_layout_ptr);
    d3d11DevCon->IASetInputLayout(vertLayout);

    d3d11DevCon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = Width;
    viewport.Height = Height;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    d3d11DevCon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbbd;
    ZeroMemory(&cbbd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));

    cbbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    cbbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cbPerObject);
    cbbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    cbbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    cbbd.MiscFlags = 0;

    hr = d3d11Device->CreateBuffer(&cbbd, NULL, &cbPerObjectBuffer);

    camPosition = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 3.0f, -8.0f, 0.0f);
    camTarget = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    camUp = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    camView = XMMatrixLookAtLH(camPosition, camTarget, camUp);
    camProjection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(0.4f * 3.14f, (float)Width / Height, 1.0f, 1000.0f);

    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC wfdesc;
    ZeroMemory(&wfdesc, sizeof(D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC));
    wfdesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME;
    wfdesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_NONE;
    hr = d3d11Device->CreateRasterizerState(&wfdesc, &WireFrame);

    d3d11DevCon->RSSetState(WireFrame);

    return true;
}

void UpdateScene()
{
    rot += .0005f;
    if (rot > 6.28f)
        rot = 0.0f;

    cube = XMMatrixIdentity();

    XMVECTOR rotaxis = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Rotation = XMMatrixRotationAxis(rotaxis, rot);
    Translation = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);

    cube = Translation * Rotation;
}

void DrawScene()
{
    float background_colour[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

    d3d11DevCon->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetView, background_colour);

    d3d11DevCon->ClearDepthStencilView(depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    WVP = cube * camView * camProjection;
    cbPerObj.WVP = XMMatrixTranspose(WVP);
    d3d11DevCon->UpdateSubresource(cbPerObjectBuffer, 0, NULL, &cbPerObj, 0, 0);
    d3d11DevCon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cbPerObjectBuffer);

    d3d11DevCon->DrawIndexed(index_count, 0, 0);

    SwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}

int messageloop() {
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    bool should_close = false;
    while (!should_close) {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) { break; }
        {
            InitScene();
            UpdateScene();
            DrawScene();
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,
    UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {

    case WM_KEYDOWN:

        if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE) {
            if (MessageBox(0, Exit,
                Exit2, MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDYES)

                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd,
        msg,
        wParam,
        lParam);
}

Variables.h
#pragma once
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")             
#pragma comment( lib, "dxgi.lib")        
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d11sdklayers.h>
#include <directxmath.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <dxgi.h>

using namespace DirectX;

ID3DBlob* vs_blob_ptr = NULL;
ID3DBlob* ps_blob_ptr = NULL;
ID3DBlob* error_blob = NULL;
ID3D11InputLayout* input_layout_ptr = NULL;

struct Vertex    //Overloaded Vertex Structure
{
    Vertex() {}
    Vertex(float x, float y, float z,
        float cr, float cg, float cb, float ca)
        : pos(x, y, z), color(cr, cg, cb, ca) {}

    XMFLOAT3 pos;
    XMFLOAT4 color;
};

Vertex v[] =
{
    Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(+1.0f, +1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(+1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(-1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(+1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
    Vertex(+1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
};

DWORD indices[] = {
    // front face
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,

    // back face
    4, 6, 5,
    4, 7, 6,

    // left face
    4, 5, 1,
    4, 1, 0,

    // right face
    3, 2, 6,
    3, 6, 7,

    // top face
    1, 5, 6,
    1, 6, 2,

    // bottom face
    4, 0, 3,
    4, 3, 7
};

UINT vertex_stride = sizeof(Vertex);
UINT vertex_offset = 0;
UINT index_count = ARRAYSIZE(indices);

UINT flags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;

LPCTSTR WndClassName = L"D3D11 Engine";
HWND hwnd = NULL;
LPCWSTR windowName = L"D3D11 Engine";
LPCWSTR Exit = L"Are you sure you want to exit? Any unsaved progress will be lost!";
LPCWSTR Exit2 = L"Exit";

IDXGISwapChain* SwapChain = NULL;
ID3D11Device* d3d11Device = NULL;
ID3D11DeviceContext* d3d11DevCon = NULL;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* renderTargetView = NULL;

ID3D11Buffer* triangleVertBuffer;
ID3D11VertexShader* VS = NULL;
ID3D11PixelShader* PS = NULL;
ID3DBlob* VS_Buffer;
ID3DBlob* PS_Buffer;
ID3D11InputLayout* vertLayout;
ID3DBlob* errorBuffer = NULL;
ID3D11Buffer* squareIndexBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer* squareVertBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer* vertex_buffer_ptr = NULL;

ID3D11DepthStencilView* depthStencilView;
ID3D11Texture2D* depthStencilBuffer;

ID3D11Buffer* cbPerObjectBuffer;

XMMATRIX WVP;
XMMATRIX World;
XMMATRIX camView;
XMMATRIX camProjection;

XMVECTOR camPosition;
XMVECTOR camTarget;
XMVECTOR camUp;

struct cbPerObject
{
    XMMATRIX  WVP;
};

cbPerObject cbPerObj;

XMMATRIX cube;
XMMATRIX Rotation;
XMMATRIX Scale;
XMMATRIX Translation;
float rot = 0.01f;

HRESULT hr;

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputElementDesc[] = {
      { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
      { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
};

UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE(inputElementDesc);

ID3D11RasterizerState* WireFrame;

VertexShader.hlsl
struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

cbuffer cbPerObject
{
    float4x4 WVP;
};

VS_OUTPUT vs_main(float4 inPos : POSITION, float4 inColor : COLOR)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;
    output.Pos = mul(inPos, WVP);
    output.Color = inColor;
    
    return output;
}

// Pixel Shader
float4 ps_main(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return input.Color; 
}


You may want to take a look at DirectX Tool Kit for DX11.

In Main.cpp,
In these lines,
 hr = d3d11Device->CreateInputLayout(inputElementDesc, numElements, vs_blob_ptr->GetBufferPointer(),
    vs_blob_ptr->GetBufferSize(), &input_layout_ptr);
d3d11DevCon->IASetInputLayout(vertLayout);

Change d3d11DevCon->IASetInputLayout(vertLayout); to d3d11DevCon->IASetInputLayout(input_layout_ptr); since you created the input layout for input_layout_ptr and not vertLayout.
This is what the output is after you correct as mentioned above,

Also, just an heads up, in your cleanup code you are releasing some stuff that you have not initialized (i.e NULL) variables like vertLayout, VS_Buffer and PS_Buffer so it's crashing once you close the window.
